# Error in JAVA while running applet program

Tags: java, applet

While I was running my applet program, I got in applet viewer window as **"Applet not initialized"** and in cmd i got the following errors!

```
    **java.lang.ClassCastException: application cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:799)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:728)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)**
```

Can anyone help me why does this error occur?

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
//<applet code="application" width=500 height=500> </applet>
public class application extends Frame implements ActionListener,ItemListener
{
Label name,regno
Button submit;
TextField tname,tregno;
String msg=" ";
public void init()
{
    name=new Label("Name");   //Adding name and regno field box
    regno=new Label("Register No");
    submit=new Button("Submit");
    tname=new TextField(20);
    tregno=new TextField(10);
    add(name); add(tname);
    add(regno); add(tregno);
    add(submit);
    submit.addActionListener(this);
    tname.addActionListener(this);
    tregno.addActionListener(this);
    }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    String str=ae.getActionCommand();
    if(str.equals("Submit"))
        msg="Your application form is submitted successfully";
    app a=new app();    //Reference for my next program called "app"
    a.setVisible(true);
    repaint();
}
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
{
    repaint();
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawString("Name: "+tname.getText(),10,160); //Printing the name and regno
    g.drawString("Register No: "+tregno.getText(),10,180);
    g.drawString(msg,250,350);
}
}
```

In the above program, I've created a basic applet structure that gets the details of the person(name and regno) and hyperlinks to another program when submit button is clicked.

Comment: Please include a code snippet of where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Applet class should be a subclass of `Applet`. Revise the class declaration so that it also `extends Applet`:

```
public class application extends ..., Applet {
    //code here
}
```

More information on `java.applet.Applet` can be found on [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html).